# AutoHotPie radial menus

Tags: windows-10, automation, autohotkey

AutoHotPie is an app that I recently discovered and it displays a context sensitive radial menu. It has an option that interacts with autohotkey and I think it's possible to write custom scripts, but I've already researched in the docs, videos, forums, etc. and it doesn't say how to do it.
Anyone who knows about this who can help me how to write custom scripts for each app?

AutoHotPie app: https://github.com/dumbeau/AutoHotPie/releases/tag/v1.0.27

Video presentation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxGt5Cr_3sk

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because author stated in a comment under a long answer that they found another solution.

Answer (score 2):

Pie or radial menus are something beautiful, but not very practical in my opinion. The number of their elements is limited.
I personally use [Hotstrings](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotstrings.htm) to run commands, files, directories or programs:

```
; All the below hotstrings will .

; execute a command instead of replacing text (X-Option)
; without automatic backspacing (B0-Option), for not going back in explorer or browser
; and "<" as ending character. Other ending characters may interfere in the active window.

#Hotstring X B0
#Hotstring EndChars <

::cw::Run C:\Windows
::su::Run %A_StartUp%
::np::Run notepad
::wd::Run winword
::vlc::Run vlc.exe
::dms::Run "D:\Scripts\myScript.ahk"
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a neat tool....

To use the radial menus to trigger an AutoHotkey script I think there are (at least) two ways to do it.

1. Compile your AutoHotkey script to an .exe and have the radial menu execute your .exe (Function: Run File) when you select a menu option. You would need to do this for each option you wanted to run (compile each option to a different .exe).
2. Code something in AutoHotkey that the radial menu option calls natively as an AutoHotkey function (i.e., no compiled .exe required, and no shell call required by the launcher to execute your code)

It sounds like you're asking about Option #2, but you may simply be asking about coding in AutoHotkey (in general). If that is the case, I would recommend learning how to code in AutoHotkey first, learning how to write programs and compile them, and then using Option #1 above for starters, which would allow you to learn the latest and greatest version of AutoHotkey (v2), while using older code for AutoHotPie (essentially written with/for AutoHotkey v1).

On the other hand, if you really want to do direct integration of v1 code into AutoHotPie, try the following

1. Assign your .ahk files to open in an editor, instead of executing them via AutoHotkey.exe by default (just an easy way to get the AutoHotPie menu file to open in an editor, instead of executing).
2. In the AutoHotPie menu, enable the option to "Use open-source AutoHotKey pie menus".
3. Finally, build and 'execute' a custom menu, and it will open in your editor as a .ahk file (PieMenu.ahk)

The PieMenu.ahk file will be saved in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\AutoHotPie\resources\src`, so if you skip step 1 and want to just go find the file that gets generated you can probably just open it at this location. Step 1 above just lets you directly open the file in an editor/debugger straight from the 'execute' option in the GUI if you want, but isn't actually necessary.

At this folder location, there are also the other files that the main PieMenu.ahk needs in order to be able to execute itself (files under `lib\`)

In the file `lib\UserPieFunctions.ahk`, you can put your own AutoHotkey functions if you want to run the whole thing natively. I'm not sure if they can be selected in the GUI anywhere (during menu creation), but if you export the .json settings for a given menu there are fields which allow you to enter your native function in the .json file, and then re-import it.

**AHPSettings-123456.json**

```
"function": "test1",
"params": {
    "arg": "This is a test"
},
"label": "Test1",
"hotkey": "",
"clickable": false,
"returnMousePos": false,
"icon": {
    "filePath": "RunScript.png",
    "WBOnly": true
```

**lib\UserPieFunctions.ahk**

```
pie_test1(arg) {
    msgbox, % arg
}
```

(Also note that the 'pie_' prefix isn't listed in the .json file)

You will also need to `#Include` the `UserPieFunctions.ahk` in the main PieMenu.ahk file...

**PieMenu.ahk**

```
#Include %A_ScriptDir%\lib\Gdip_All.ahk
#Include %A_ScriptDir%\lib\GdipHelper.ahk
#Include %A_ScriptDir%\lib\BGFunks.ahk
#Include %A_ScriptDir%\lib\PieFunctions.ahk
#Include %A_ScriptDir%\lib\Json.ahk
#Include %A_ScriptDir%\lib\UserPieFunctions.ahk   ; <-- add this line
```

I didn't get the argument parameter to work, but it's probably something simple. These are just a few ideas to maybe get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and I hope that this tool has been useful to someone. I discovered an easier way to do it with Radial Menus v4, a tool written directly in ahk that provides many options with radial menus.